# jQuery Datatables populate search data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

On document.ready, my Datatable loads accordingly.

What I need to do is build a feature that reloads the Datatable if the user conducts a search.

So the Datatable loads like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $('#searchSubmit').on('click', function()  // used for searching
  {
    var searchbooking = $('#searchbooking').val();
    var searchquote = $('#searchquote').val();
    var searchtli = $('#searchtli').val();

    if(searchbooking == "" && searchquote == "" && searchtli == "")
    {
      $('.message').text('You did not enter any search criteria.');
      return false; // making sure they enter something
    }
    else
    {
      $.post('api/searchAll.php', {searchbooking:searchbooking, searchquote:searchquote, searchtli:searchtli}, function(data)
      {
        // what do i do here???
        // how do I get the return results to load
      });
    }
  });
  // if the user does not enter any search parameters, load everything
  $('#example1').DataTable({    
    "ajax": {
      "url": "api/displayQnams.php",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataSrc": ''
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "" },
      { "data": "column1" },
      { "data": "column2" },
      { "data": "column3" }
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
    // and so on
  });
});
```

As you will see in the above code, when the document is ready, if the user does not conduct a search, I load all of the data from the process called 'displayQnams.php'.

But if the user conducts a search, the parameters are sent to another process called 'qnamsSearch.php'.

How do I reload the datatable with the search results from 'qnamsSearch.php'?

I tried to create a variable from inside the post:

```
var dataUrl = data;
```

And I tried to call that variable in the ajax call:

```
"ajax": {
  "url": dataUrl,
  "type": "POST",
  "dataSrc": ''
}
```

But the Datatable will not display anything and there are no console errors.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this.

After user click search button, below is the flow:

1. Clear datatables - [datatables clear()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear())
2. Add new data to the table - [datatables rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add())
3. Adjust column size (optional) - [datatables adjust.columns()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust())
4. Redraw back datatable with new data - [datatables draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var datatable = $('#example1').DataTable({    
           "ajax": {
               "url": "api/displayQnams.php",
               "type": "POST",
               "dataSrc": ''
           },
           "columns": [
               { "data": "" },
               { "data": "column1" },
               { "data": "column2" },
               { "data": "column3" }
           ],
           "iDisplayLength": 25,
           "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]]
       });

       $('#searchSubmit').on('click', function(){
           var searchbooking = $('#searchbooking').val();
           var searchquote = $('#searchquote').val();
           var searchtli = $('#searchtli').val();

           if(searchbooking == "" && searchquote == "" && searchtli == ""){
               $('.message').text('You did not enter any search criteria.');
               return false; // making sure they enter something
           } else {
               $.post(
                   'api/searchAll.php',
                   { searchbooking:searchbooking, searchquote:searchquote, searchtli:searchtli },
                   function(data) {
                       var newData = data;
                       datatable.clear().draw();
                       datatable.rows.add(newData); // Add new data
                       datatable.columns.adjust().draw(); // Redraw the DataTable
                   });
               }
           });
    });
   ```

Comment: I get an error that reads: datatable is not defined.  Any thoughts?